Find the asymptotic expansion of the integral
Prove:$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{(1+x^2)^n}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4n^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{15\sqrt{\pi}}{32n^{\frac{5}{2}}}+O(n^{-\frac{7}{2}}),\quad n\to+\infty.$$
I use the Laplace method and obtained an estimate for the first item$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$, but I don't know how to get the asymptotic expansion of the integral.

Performing the change of variables from $x$ to $t$ via $
{\rm e}^t  = 1 + x^2$ transforms the integral into
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - nt} t^{ - 1/2} \sin ({\rm e}^t  - 1)\frac{{{\rm e}^t }}{2}\sqrt {\frac{t}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}}} \,{\rm d}t} .
$$
By expanding
$$
\sin ({\rm e}^t  - 1)\frac{{{\rm e}^t }}{2}\sqrt {\frac{t}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}}}  = \frac{1}{2}t + \frac{5}{8}t^2  +  \ldots 
$$
near $t=0$, and applying Watson's lemma, we can obtain the desired asymptotic expansion.
Alternatively, you can use Laplace's method in its more advanced form.

Thank you for your solution ！
